# DataTable not rendring Gridview after button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-plugins, datatables

In my page when it's creating, everything is working fine but when I am clicking on the button to show the selected row, then my grid view is not rendering as a datatable. What I need to do to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

My script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=gvTest]').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(this).find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
                "responsive": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                
                 
            });
        });
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var table = $('#gvTest').DataTable();
            $('#gvTest tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
            });
              
      
            $('#btnRead').click(function () {
           var ids = $.map(table.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
               return item[0]
                 });               
            });
           
    } );
    </script>
```

My Grid:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
     <ContentTemplate>

     <asp:GridView  ID="gvTest" Width="100%" runat="server"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
      <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField  DataField="PatientID"  HeaderText="Patient ID" >
           </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField  DataField="PatientName"  HeaderText="PatientName" >
           </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField  DataField="Age"  HeaderText="Age" >
           </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Sex" DataField="Sex"  >
           </asp:BoundField>
           <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Mod" DataField="Modality"  >                                 
      </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When my page is created:

[image]

Everything is working fine, but when I click a button then this happens:

[image]

What do I need to do now to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after using a lots of others code i did'nt get a proper solution so i used this on my page load  and its working fine

```
gvTest.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
//adds <thead> and <tbody> elements
gvTest.HeaderRow.TableSection =
TableRowSection.TableHeader;
```

Answer (score 2):

The UpdatePanel refreshes the DOM, so any changes made to it with jQuery are lost. You need to call `DataTable()` again after an Async PostBack. You can use the `PageRequestManager` for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        createDataTable();
    });

    createDataTable();

    function createDataTable() {
        var table = $('#gvTest').DataTable();
        $('#gvTest tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to fix this issue is by implementing this in `pageLoad` function.
In this case I used a Gridview:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $("<thead></thead>").append($("#grvPast tr:first")).prependTo($("#grvPast"));
    $('#grvPast').dataTable();
}
```