# DropDownList losing style in UpdatePanel after PostBack in Asp.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I am using select2 plugin for dropdownlist in asp.net c# which has autopostback true, but when placed in updatepanel its working fine on first page load but when postback happens its styling is gone and dropdownlist is showed in default asp.net format.

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-12">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="type" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label for="bktype">Type</label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="bktype" runat="server" CssClass="form-control select2 round" Style="width: 100%" required="" data-validation-required-message="Select a Type" data-placeholder="Select a Type" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="bk_type" DataTextField="typename" DataValueField="typeId" OnSelectedIndexChanged="bktype_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="">Select a Type</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="bk_type" runat="server" ConnectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\EReader.mdf;Integrated Security=True" ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [BTypes] ORDER BY [typename]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4 col-12">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="genre" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <label for="bkgenres">Genres</label>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="bkgenres" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control select2 round" multiple="multiple" Style="width: 100%" required="" data-validation-required-message="Select Genres" data-placeholder="Select Genres" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Value="">Select Genres</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

[Before PostBack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL9hA.png)
[After Postback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R465k.png)

After PostBack happens select2 all styleing is gone search box of select2 is also gone. Please help me out.

Comment: See my answer here. Replace datatable with select2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294718/5836671

Comment: where should i put my dropdownlist id? Its pretty confusing for me

Comment: In the function `createDataTable()` replace the logic with the code used to generate a style ddl.